# how do I get kinect depth image data in centimeters using the libfreenect python bindings?

Tags: python, kinect, depth, units-of-measurement

I am trying to get an xbox kinect depth image in some reasonable units (cm or in don't really care) using the libfreenect Python bindings.

To that end I am trying to set the default kinect depth mode to registered (FREENECT_DEPTH_REGISTERD in the C API; DEPTH_REGISTERED in the Python one according to freenect.pyx) via:

```
freenect.set_depth_mode(freenect.DEPTH_REGISTERED)
```

But the call fails with an error:

```
TypeError: set_video_mode() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (1 given)
```

After looking at freenect.c I found the other two arguments but that lead down another rabbit hole. Not sure what to do. I'd like for there to be a nice python method that I can call. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 other arguments taken by freenect.set_depth_mode are the device and the resolution. So you have to provide a device to the function. For the resolution, you can use freenect.RESOLUTION_MEDIUM, it is the default one.

A working example would be :

```
mdev = freenect.open_device(freenect.init(), 0)
freenect.set_depth_mode(mdev, freenect.RESOLUTION_MEDIUM, freenect.DEPTH_REGISTERED)
freenect.runloop(dev=mdev)
```